# Get Custom Field Limits using API

Tags: limits

Salesforce has defined custom field limits in the given [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apicalls.htm).

For eg :- Limit for Custom Fields for Developer Edition Org is 500 Custom Fields per Object.
We can also request Salesforce and increase the limits from the default limits defined for that edition.

Is there any API using which we retrieve the Custom Field Limits?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been reviewing the API's and as far as I can see there is nothing. A close possibility was the [REST API resource for Limits](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/resources_limits.htm), however it is more about day to day operation limits rather than configuration ones. Shame...

[image]